# Two ML.NET models in one project

Tags: c#, ml.net

Is it possible to have two different ML.NET models in one project? For example, one for recommendation and one for classification.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have multiple MLContext in your application. Each MLContext has its own model. I have for example an application that uses 5 models for different predictions.